# Very Slow Data Transfer between two Internal Volume on Synology NAS

Tags: nas, synology-diskstation

I tried both File Copy within File Station, both Move to and Copy to had the same results. I try changing Shared Folder location to a different volume. The results were the same.

Even with Multiple GB files, ( Seq Write and not 4K Small Files ) , it max out at 18MB/s. That is even slower than my USB 2.0 HDD speed. For something that is transferring internally under the same NAS between two SATA 3Gbps HDD that should be able to perform within 150-200MB/s

Anyone have any idea why that is the case.  Here is an image of my transfer speed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmUUn.jpg

This is No Rebuild, No Expansion, No Encryption, No File Indexing, No Speed Limit in File Station. This is on an ancient 212J, but CPU speed should not make much difference to file transfer. And neither was CPU speed maxed out during transfer.

Anyone could provide a technical explanation as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

FileCopy in the GUI has always been rather slow. I've never seen it get anywhere near possible maximum transfer speeds. It is ok to push a few small files around, but really slow for bigger jobs.
No idea why that is but it seems as if the FileStation app uses a quite inefficent backend to do the actual work on the NAS. (Remember that the FileStation app runs in your webbrowser on your client computer. It needs to send instructions to the NAS where some background process does the actual work.)

Whenever I need to shuffle stuff around on one of my Syno's I just login with SSH and do it on the commandline.
It is usually 2 to 3 times faster to use the `cp` and `mv` commands. `rsync` is also available for more complex things and to move stuf between 2 Syno's across the LAN.

Comment: Tried SSH, speed were about the same.